# Plot not showing up using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, roc

I am trying to plot two true positive rate and false positive rate values for two different cases. While plotting, the second plot cancels out the display of the first sort of.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import os
import sys
from scipy.spatial import distance
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def fextract(fname1, fname2):
    file1 = open(fname1,'r')
    file2 = open(fname2,'r')
    cnt = 122
    data1 = file1.readlines()
    data2 = file2.readlines()
    print(len(data1))
    tpr = np.zeros((1,cnt))
    fpr = np.zeros((1,cnt))
    cnt2 = 0
    for x in data1:
        if(cnt2 == 120):
            break
        tpr[0,cnt2] = float(x)
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 1

    cnt2 = 0
    for x in data2:
        if(cnt2 == 120):
            break
        fpr[0,cnt2] = float(x)
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 1

    return tpr, fpr     

def plotfig(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    f1 = plt.figure()
    lg = plt.plot(x2[0,:], y2[0,:], label="Skin Color (With Chrominance)")
    lg = plt.plot(x1[0,:], y1[0,:], label="Skin Color")
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.show()



tpr,fpr = fextract('tp.txt','fp.txt')
tpr2,fpr2 = fextract('tp2.txt','fp2.txt')
tpr3,fpr3 = fextract('tp3.txt','fp3.txt')

tpr4,fpr4 = fextract('tp7.txt','fp7.txt')
tpr5,fpr5 = fextract('tp8.txt','fp8.txt')
tpr6,fpr6 = fextract('tp9.txt','fp9.txt')

plotfig(fpr,tpr,fpr4,tpr4)
plotfig(fpr2,tpr2,fpr5,tpr5)
plotfig(fpr3,tpr3,fpr6,tpr6)
```

[image: Figure plotting the True Positive and False Positive values of both cases]

As seen above, the the orange line stops midway and the blue gets plotted completely.

Comment: Can someone please help. I tried a lot and it's not working

Comment: Just do `print(len(data1), data1[-1])` and the same for `data2`. They either run further than 122 elements, or the x-values are nearer to each other. How can somebody not knowing the data give a precise answer to your question?